# Manually extend col by pixel amount

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this is sort of a hack.
I have two cols in a row.
The left ones margin is set to -20px.
This causes everything to shift to the left by 20px.

I am wondering is there a way to extend the right col by 20px

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding to push it out

```
padding-right: 20px;
```